# Configure nginx as reverse proxy http uri -> private individual servers

Tags: nginx, iis, reverse-proxy

I have a server, with no domain set on it. I access it by ip on port 80. I have IIS on it with 3 websites on ports 8080, 8081, 8082.
All I want is when someone enters SERVER_IP/foo1, nginx show content from 192.168.1.100:8080

SERVER_IP/foo2 -> 192.168.1.100:8081

SERVER_IP/foo3 -> 192.168.1.100:8082

these private servers are complicated web applications and have authentications, other pages and etc.
I appreciate any help.
my current config is putting

```
location  /foo1/   {  
        if ($request_uri ~* "/foo1/(.*)") { 
        proxy_pass  http://192.168.1.100:8080/$1;
        }
```

in default server block of nginx, and obviously it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "obviously" here, you demonstrate the problem and post full configuration, error log, and ideally a curl or similar to show what happens.

However I think something like this should work, though you may have to play with the expression a little - I don't write them often so it takes me a while to get them right. There are a few examples on [this page](http://www.liaohuqiu.net/posts/nginx-proxy-pass/).

```
location ~ ^/foo1/(.*)$ {
  proxy_pass       http://192.168.1.100:8080/$1;
}
```

It might work better with something more like this as the first line

```
location /foo1/(.*)$ {
```